# i want to write a python program that converts an integer to its corresponding month

Tags: python

I want to add a error message if it exceeds 12 or if a character is entered without any if statements. here is what I have written so far:

```
import calender

def get_mont_name(month_number):
    try:
        return calender.month_name[month_number]
    except IndexError:
        print("'[]' is not a valid month number".format(month_number))
```

Comment: You already get an `IndexError` in that case. Why not return the error code in the `except` block? I'm a little confused about what's being asked here.

Comment: The only problem I see is the module is `calendar` not `calender`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is really close to working!

Firstly, you've spelt calendar wrong, but I assume this is just a typo.

You've slightly misused format() which is probably causing your issue. Replacing your print statement with the following should fix it:

```
print("{num} is not a valid month number".format(num = month_number))
```

The curly brackets allow the format() method to identify the parts of the string you'd like to modify.

I hope this helps!